# Using grep to find partial matches

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match

i want to subset a dataframe througth a list of variables, and those should be present in multiple columns

DO_concatenated

```
    LINHAA LINHAB  LINHAC LINHAD  LINHAII
1   *R58X   NA      NA      NA     NA
2   *P285   *P220   *P000   NA     NA
3   *A419   *N390   *I694   NA     NA
4   *G80X   NA      NA      NA     NA
5   *I64X   *I10X   *E119   *D649  NA
6   *R688   *J189   *C920   NA     NA
7   *A419   *J159   *C349   *J440  *E149
8   *A419   *J159   *C73X   *I10X  NA
9   *P269   *E872   *P369   NA     *P000
10  *P369   *P285   *Q870   NA     NA
```

These numbers represents some codes of ICD10, and I want to filter only codes of rares diseases, that are contained in a data frame named "rare_diseases". It structure looks like that:

```
   CID.10       rare.disease
1   D820    Sindrome de Wiskott-Aldrich
2   D821    Sindrome de Di George
3   E778    Sindrome de glicoproteinas deficientes em carboidratos
4   F70     Retardo mental leve
5   F71     Retardo mental moderado
6   F72     Retardo mental grave
```

So, I've created a list with the first column of the second dataframe (`cid10`) and tried to make a grep:

```
a = DO_concatenated[(grep(cid10, DO_concatenated$LINHAA) | grep(cid10, DO_concatenated$LINHAB) |
                 grep(cid10, DO_concatenated$LINHAC) | grep(cid10, DO_concatenated$LINHAD) |
                   grep(cid10, DO_concatenated$LINHAII)),]
```

But, it returns a data frame with 0 variables

What am I doing wrong and how I can make a partial match, as the first df has a "*" before each code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're example does not have any matches, so using it would result in zero rows. I changed the examples a little to illustrate how to subset the data based on a condition that is applied over several columns.

First, here is the data we will work with:

```
DO_concatenated <- read.table(text = "    LINHAA LINHAB  LINHAC LINHAD  LINHAII
1   *F70   NA      NA      NA     NA
2   *P285   *P220   *P000   NA     NA
3   *A419   *N390   *I694   NA     NA
4   *G80X   NA      NA      NA     NA
5   *I64X   *D820   *E119   *D649  NA
6   *R688   *J189   *C920   NA     NA
7   *A419   *J159   *C349   *J440  *F70
8   *D820   *J159   *C73X   *D820  NA
9   *P269   *F70   *P369   NA     *P000
10  *P369   *E778   *Q870   NA     NA", stringsAsFactors = F)
DO_concatenated
#>    LINHAA LINHAB LINHAC LINHAD LINHAII
#> 1    *F70   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
#> 2   *P285  *P220  *P000   <NA>    <NA>
#> 3   *A419  *N390  *I694   <NA>    <NA>
#> 4   *G80X   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
#> 5   *I64X  *D820  *E119  *D649    <NA>
#> 6   *R688  *J189  *C920   <NA>    <NA>
#> 7   *A419  *J159  *C349  *J440    *F70
#> 8   *D820  *J159  *C73X  *D820    <NA>
#> 9   *P269   *F70  *P369   <NA>   *P000
#> 10  *P369  *E778  *Q870   <NA>    <NA>

rare_diseases <- read.table(text = "   CID.10       rare.disease
1   D820    'Sindrome de Wiskott-Aldrich'
2   D821    'Sindrome de Di George'
3   E778    'Sindrome de glicoproteinas deficientes em carboidratos'
4   F70     'Retardo mental leve'
5   F71     'Retardo mental moderado'
6   F72     'Retardo mental grave'", stringsAsFactors = F)
rare_diseases
#>   CID.10                                           rare.disease
#> 1   D820                            Sindrome de Wiskott-Aldrich
#> 2   D821                                  Sindrome de Di George
#> 3   E778 Sindrome de glicoproteinas deficientes em carboidratos
#> 4    F70                                    Retardo mental leve
#> 5    F71                                Retardo mental moderado
#> 6    F72                                   Retardo mental grave
```

Now that we have the data, we first convert the row names to a new column, then we go from wide to long format using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`, then we apply the filter based on the `CID.10` in the `rare_diseases` dataframe. Lastly, we `pivot_wider` to get back the wide format. This method will only keep the row and code for the rare disease.

```
library(tidyverse)

DO_concatenated %>%
  rownames_to_column("row") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("LINH"), names_to = "col", values_to = "codes") %>%
  filter(grepl(paste(rare_diseases$CID.10, collapse = "|"), codes))  %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "row", names_from = "col", values_from = codes)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   row   LINHAA LINHAB LINHAII LINHAD
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> 
#>   1     *F70   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
#>   5     <NA>   *D820  <NA>    <NA>  
#>   7     <NA>   <NA>   *F70    <NA>  
#>   8     *D820  <NA>   <NA>    *D820 
#>   9     <NA>   *F70   <NA>    <NA>  
#>   10    <NA>   *E778  <NA>    <NA>
```

Another option if you want to keep everything in a row that contains a rare disease would be to use `filter_at` to filter any row where at least one column has a rare disease. Or we could collapse all the columns into one column, use `grepl` to filter, then re-separate the columns.

```
DO_concatenated %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("LINH")), 
            any_vars(grepl(paste(rare_diseases$CID.10, collapse = "|"), .)))
#>   LINHAA LINHAB LINHAC LINHAD LINHAII
#> 1   *F70   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
#> 2  *I64X  *D820  *E119  *D649    <NA>
#> 3  *A419  *J159  *C349  *J440    *F70
#> 4  *D820  *J159  *C73X  *D820    <NA>
#> 5  *P269   *F70  *P369   <NA>   *P000
#> 6  *P369  *E778  *Q870   <NA>    <NA>

DO_concatenated %>%
  unite(col = "new", sep = "_") %>%
  filter(grepl(paste(rare_diseases$CID.10, collapse = "|"), new)) %>%
  separate(new, into = colnames(DO_concatenated), sep = "_")
#>   LINHAA LINHAB LINHAC LINHAD LINHAII
#> 1   *F70     NA     NA     NA      NA
#> 2  *I64X  *D820  *E119  *D649      NA
#> 3  *A419  *J159  *C349  *J440    *F70
#> 4  *D820  *J159  *C73X  *D820      NA
#> 5  *P269   *F70  *P369     NA   *P000
#> 6  *P369  *E778  *Q870     NA      NA
```

And if you want a solution in `base` R

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(colnames(DO_concatenated), function(x){
          DO_concatenated[grepl(paste(rare_diseases$CID.10, collapse = "|"),
                                DO_concatenated[,which(colnames(DO_concatenated) == x)]),]
          })
        )
#>    LINHAA LINHAB LINHAC LINHAD LINHAII
#> 1    *F70   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
#> 8   *D820  *J159  *C73X  *D820    <NA>
#> 5   *I64X  *D820  *E119  *D649    <NA>
#> 9   *P269   *F70  *P369   <NA>   *P000
#> 10  *P369  *E778  *Q870   <NA>    <NA>
#> 81  *D820  *J159  *C73X  *D820    <NA>
#> 7   *A419  *J159  *C349  *J440    *F70
```

Comment: Sorry! I just used the firsts lines of each df to illustrate its structure, but DO_concatenated has 1.312.664 rows, and cid10 is a list of 119 elements

Comment: I tried the ´base´ code and it works perfectly, thank you! But can you explain to me why my first code doesn't work